# Html5 tex-decoration on div

Tags: html, css

In html5 it is possible to encase a div in an a tag but I have a problem with the text decoration text-decoration:none do not work

```
  <div id="messageconv">
  <a href="#">
  <div class="messageconv">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/soft-scraps/16/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.cqed.org/IMG/cache-30x30/5a528e158e13938e9c7ac616a6cd6d0b-30x30.png" alt="">
  test</div>
 </a>
 </div>
```

css:

```
#messageconv {
height:292px;
border: 1px solid #cfced8;
margin-right:5px;
width:170px;
float:left;
text-align:left;
}
.messageconv {
background-color:#e7e5f1;
padding:5px;
margin:2px;
}
.messageconv img {
vertical-align:middle;
margin-right:5px;
border:0px;
}
.messageconv a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Example here

http://www.cssdesk.com/wJkRX

Comment: `text-decoration` is not a valid property for images

Comment: put text-decoration on the <a> element

Comment: Personally I'd avoid using the same name for an ID *and* a class.

Comment: @Paulie_D he doesn't have it in the inspector in Chrome. Adding text-decoration:none to #messageconv a removes the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo

```
.messageconv a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

should be

```
#messageconv a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! a different point of view is always useful in some situations